# How to pass selected option from drop-down to form for record update

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to build a record update form where I need to pass a value from a drop-down list to an update query. The drop-down list options come from a select query. I am close to accepting defeat but thought I'd first reach out to the collective brain-trust. I've console logged where the trouble seems to be. With the reference error, the "lat_pulldown" is one of the drop-down list items. I'm confused as to why it would need to be defined, and have not been able to identify the cause of the syntax error.

Much thanks for any help or suggestions!

[image]

```
<?php
    // Include config file
    require_once "config.php";
    
    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $stationtype = $selectstatype = "";
    $stationtype_err = "";
    
    // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
        // Get hidden input value
        $id = $_POST["id"];
    
        // Validate stationtype
        $input_stationtype = trim($_POST["stationtype"]);
        //$input_selectstatype = trim($_POST["stationtype"]);
        
        echo "<script> console.log('log1 ') </script>";
        echo "<script> console.log($input_stationtype) </script>"; //log1
        
        if(empty($input_stationtype )){
            $stationtype_err = "Please select a station type.";     
        } else{
            $stationtype  = $input_stationtype ;
        }
        
        // Check input errors before inserting in database
        if(empty($stationtype_err)){
            
            // Prepare an update statement
            $sql = " UPDATE stactrak_WPCPH.reptbl1 SET stationtype=?, reading_time=reading_time WHERE setfnsecs=? ";
            
            echo "<script> console.log('log2 ') </script>";
            echo "<script> console.log($sql) </script>"; //log2
            
            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
                
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $param_stationtype, $param_setfnsecs);
                
                // Set parameters
                $param_stationtype = $stationtype;
                $param_setfnsecs = $id;
                
                echo "<script> console.log('log3 ') </script>";
                echo "<script> console.log($param_setfnsecs) </script>"; //log3
                echo "<script> console.log($param_stationtype) </script>"; //log3
                
                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                
                //echo "<script> console.log('log3 ') </script>";
                //echo "<script> console.log(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) </script>"; //log3
                
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                    echo "<script> location='https://stactraklog.com/set-crud/index.php' </script>";
                } else{ 
                    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Update Record</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            .wrapper{
                width: 500px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"
                        <div class="page-header">
                            <h2>Update Set Record</h2>
                        </div>
                        <p>Please edit the station type value and submit to update the set.</p>
                        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                            
                            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($stationtype_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <label>current stationtype</label>
                                <input type="text" name="stationtypeold" readonly class="form-control" value="<?php echo $stationtype; ?>">
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($stationtype_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <label>enter station type ...</label>
                                  <select class="form-control" name="stationtype" id="stationtype">
                                    <?php
                                    // Include config file
                                    require_once "config.php";
                                    $sql = "SELECT ".
                                    "    s.stationtype ".                    
                                    "FROM ".
                                    "    stactrak_WPCPH.reptbl1 r, ".
                                    "    stactrak_WPCPH.stations s ".
                                    "WHERE".
                                    "    1 = 1 ".
                                    "    and r.machname = s.machname ".
                                    "    and r.setfnsecs = $id ".
                                    "UNION ".
                                    "SELECT ' ' stationtype ".
                                    "ORDER BY 1";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                                    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                        $optionstatype = $rows['stationtype'];
                                        echo "<option value='$optionstatype'>$optionstatype</option>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                  </select>
                                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $stationtype_err;?></span>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($stationtype_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <label>new stationtype</label>
                                <input type="text" name="newstationtype" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $stationtype; ?>">
                                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $stationtype_err;?></span>
                            </div>
                            
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div>`enter code here`
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: $input_stationtype is "lat_pulldown". When you console.log() it, it is not a string as it doesn't have quotes (""). JavaScript is looking for a variable called lat_pulldown. But no such variable is defined. If you want latpulldown as a string, then put quotes around it. Like echo "<script> console.log('$input_stationtype') </script>"

Comment: Thanks very much Shah! Your feedback fixed the reference error problem which then allowed me to further troubleshoot, and eventually solve the problem.Thanks again!